# DocuSign: set expiration in JWT Token - the access token is always generated with one hour expiration

Tags: jwt, docusignapi

We're using the **DocuSign SDK** (version 3.5.0) We are developing an integration with DocuSign using **JWT authentication**.

In order for testing purpose, I want the expiration time to be short such as 300, 1800,..

But every time I generate a token, the expiration time is 3600. Is this an issue or I am missing some thing else?

```
token = api_client.request_jwt_user_token(client_id=client_id,
                                          user_id=user_id,
                                          oauth_host_name=oauth_host_name,
                                          private_key_bytes=private_key,
                                          expires_in=1800)
```

**result ---->**

```
{'access_token': 'the_accesstoken',
              'data': None,
              'expires_in': '3600',
              'refresh_token': None,
              'scope': None,
              'token_type': 'Bearer'}
```

Answer (score 0):

The ExpiresIn value sets how long the *assertion itself* is valid for. At this time there is no way to request an access token with a modified expiration timer.

There is an outstanding enhancement request to allow short-lived tokens for testing in the Demo environment. That request is tracked internally as ID-4585.